# Independence of two events with non empty intersection

Tags: probability

Let $A, B$ be two non empty events. If they are disjoint, i. e. exclusive, they are not independent. In the case they are not  disjoint, they can be either independent or not independent. Intuitively, in the case two events have non empty intersection, the occurrence of one event will condition the occurrence of the other one since their intersection is not empty. In other words, I don't understand how $P(A|B) = P(A). $I am thus confused.

Can you provide an explanation and an example of 2 non empty events with non empty intersection which are independent?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do not confuse the terms "*Mutually exclusive*" and "*Independent.*"  They mean totally different things.  Mutual exclusivity has to do with whether or not $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Independence has to do with whether or not $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  As for an example of independent events which are not disjoint... look at practically any example of independent events out there... for example the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the events "$x$ is even", $\{2,4\}$ and "$x$ is prime" $\{2,3\}$.

Comment: Also, I would go a step further, rather than just stating that $A,B$ be nonempty events, you should further stipulate that $A$ and $B$ are not "impossible events" as well, i.e. that $Pr(A)>0$.  If both $A$ and $B$ are possible events and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then it follows that $A$ and $B$ are not independent since $Pr(A)\times Pr(B)>0=Pr(A\cap B)$.  Otherwise, if $A$ and $B$ are nonempty but still impossible events you could still have that $A$ and $B$ are independent despite being disjoint since you would have $Pr(A)\times Pr(B)=0=Pr(A\cap B)$.

Comment: What is an impossible non empty event? Can you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: "impossible" or perhaps more correctly "almost-impossible" events refer to those events whose probability is zero.  An example of an (*almost*)impossible event would be selecting the number $1.0257$ when picking a *real number* uniformly at random from the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: Ok. So that's what in measure theory is called a measure zero set in respect to some measure function. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independence $P(A|B) = P(A)$ is the math way of saying that knowing $B$ does not affect the probability of $A$.  E.g.

- $A =$ whether a first fair coin flip is Heads
- $B =$ whether a *second* fair coin flip is Heads (assuming these are "normal" coins that don't affect each other)

So $P(A) = P(B) = P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 1/2$ while $P(A\cap B) = 1/4$.

Perhaps this is where you're confused: Conditioned on $B$ does "shrink" the sample space (to the subset which is $B$), so it does potentially "shrink" the ways how $A$ can happen (or not happen).  However, independence means the "shrinkages" are "exactly proportional" in some sense, so that it doesn't change the *probability* of $A$ happening.  In this specific example:

- The full sample space is $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ (where the first symbol denotes $A$'s result and the second symbol $B$'s result)
- Conditioned on $B$ "shrinks" the space to $\{HH, TH\}$
- However, the prob of $A$ happening was $\frac24 = \frac12$ "before" and is still $\frac12$ "afterwards"

Answer (score 5):

Take a 4-sided die with the numbers 1 to 4. Check the events:

- result is $\le 2$.
- result is odd.

Another possibility: if $P(A) = 1$ and $B\subset A$ then
$$P(A) P(B) = P(B) = P(A\cap B).$$

Comment: Thanks. I understand the formal definition but I don't get the intuition though. Can you maybe give an example of 2 events with non empty intersection which are not independent just for observing the difference?

Comment: @user249018 rather than the result is $\leq 2$ change it to the result is $\leq 3$.

Comment: That's a special case where one set is contained in the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Karnaugh table for 2 events $A, B$ and their complementary events $A^C,B^C$ with, in the boxes, the different probabilities of possible events :

[image]

Saying that $A$ and $B$ are independent is thus expressed in the following way (under the constraint $x+y+z \leq 1$) :

Rational or real values of $x,y,z$ are such that :

$$P(A \cap B)=P(A) \times P(B) \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ x=(x+y)(x+z)$$

which can be realized in an infinite number of ways...